# Querying optional string in mongoose 4.0

Tags: mongoose

I have a field named ***Category*** which i want to query.
I am using

```
Deal.find({Category:categoryName},function(err, doc){
...
}
```

This works fine when giving a value for *categoryName*.
I want to return all the entries of the database if *categoryName* is empty.

i.e

```
If categoryName is given
     then return specific entries
Else if categoryName is empty 
     then return all entries
```

I can use if else statement to write 2 different queries but I have 4 more fields like ***Category*** and i have to do similar query for all the 4 fields. i.e. a total of 16 if else statements.

What is the best method to do this type of query?

Answer (score 0):

Create a query object based on those conditionals prior to assigning it as the **`find()`** argument:

```
var query = {};
if (categotyName !== undefined || categoryName !== "") query["Category"] = categoryName;

Deal.find(query, function(err, doc){
    ...
}
```